# block hound throw exception in spring webflux

Tags: redis, spring-webflux, reactor

I'm trying to understand the behavior of non-blocking system, but not as expected, when i pass the data in @RequestParam, everything working fine,
but if i send data in @RequestBody Everything goes wrong. Please help me out.

```
   //first method, it is working fine
@PostMapping("/test1")
public Mono<Boolean> test2(@RequestParam String name) {
    return reactiveRedisTemplate.opsForHash().put("user", name, name);
}

    //this method not working 
@PostMapping("/test1")
public Mono<Boolean> test2(@RequestBody LoginModel loginModel) {
    return reactiveRedisTemplate.opsForHash().put("user", loginModel.getUsername(), loginModel);
}

    //this is also not working
@PostMapping("/test1")
public Mono<Boolean> test2(@RequestBody LoginModel loginModel) {

    return Mono.just(loginModel).flatMap(item -> reactiveRedisTemplate.opsForHash().put("user", item.getUsername(), item));
}
```

> Block hound exception

```
reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! sun.misc.Unsafe#park
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

Error has been observed at the following site(s):
|_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.caretap.docapp.test.TestController#test2(LoginModel) [DispatcherHandler]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/auth/test1" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(CompletableFuture.java:1693) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3323) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(CompletableFuture.java:1729) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at io.lettuce.core.DefaultConnectionFuture.get(DefaultConnectionFuture.java:69) ~[lettuce-core-6.0.2.RELEASE.jar:6.0.2.RELEASE]
at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:315) ~[lettuce-core-6.0.2.RELEASE.jar:6.0.2.RELEASE]
at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:211) ~[lettuce-core-6.0.2.RELEASE.jar:6.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1459) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1230) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:989) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:445) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:98) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.ReactiveRedisTemplate.lambda$doInConnection$0(ReactiveRedisTemplate.java:198) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.call(MonoSupplier.java:85) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen.subscribe(FluxUsingWhen.java:80) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:202) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1789) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1789) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:305) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1789) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1789) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:336) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1789) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1789) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:259) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:457) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:258) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.request(FluxReceive.java:130) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollect.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeek.java:170) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:168) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.lambda$subscribe$2(FluxReceive.java:147) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-common-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-transport-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]

Comment: please dont do another post with the same question. You can edit and update your old post.

Comment: `sun.misc.Unsafe.park` is basically like a `thread.wait` call. Im guessing you have problems with your redis connection, or something with redis that is faulty.

Comment: If redis connection is a blocking then why first method is working fine

Comment: Maybe because it is actually not working fine under the hood. Debug your code.

Comment: hey, it is issue of lettuce connection, when i have send data in body then everything work on main thread, so that block hound tell blocking things, so should i do everything method in an another thread, is it optimal solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001283/reactive-redis-lettuce-always-publishing-to-single-thread